# Stop spinning down internal disk

Tags: hard-disk, power-management

My laptop has a WDC WD10JPCX-24UE4T0. It spins down after 5 seconds of idle. That is pretty annoying.

How can I change the spindown time?

I have tried:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-disks
hdparm -S 200 /dev/sda
hd-idle -i 100 -a sda
```

The disk spins down after 5 seconds still.

Answer (score 4):

Not only annoying! It would make the drive dead in a matter of months probably.

So far I have found out you need to change [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Power_Management) level to allow suspending disks by setting:

```
hdparm -B 127 /dev/sdX
```

Where 127 is actually the maximum value allowing suspending drives (spindown).

---

And then you can change the suspend value with:

```
hdparm -S 241 /dev/sdX
```

From the man page:

Values from 241 to 251 specify from 1 to 11 units of 30 minutes, yielding timeouts from 30 minutes to 5.5 hours.

---

You'll need a service file for this to persist on suspend and reboot. Wait for it.

Something like this should work:

```
[Unit]
Description=hdparm sleep
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/hdparm -S 241 -B 127 /dev/sda

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target suspend.target
```

Save it as root to:

```
/lib/systemd/system/hdparm.service
```

Then you'll need to activate it with:

```
systemctl enable hdparm.service
```

Take this service file only as an example, read thoroughly the [`hdparm` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm)!

Comment: How do you the op is using both Linux and systemd? Great answer +1

Comment: Did not solve the problem. It still spins down very fast (less than 30 seconds).